# Update Trigger needs to cause an update on same table and fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I'm having trouble getting this update trigger to work.  I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

So I have a table of customers called `tblCustomers` that has fields:

- `ActivationStatus`
- `RateClass`
- `ParentCustomerID`  (indicates what customer (if any) this customer is a "child" of)

Whenever an UPDATE happens on the `ActivationStatus` or `RateClass` of a parent Customer, any children Customers need to also get updated with the same values.

I currently have:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [tblCustomers_UTrig] ON [tblCustomers] FOR UPDATE AS

-- If ActivationStatus updated, need to update any child Customers too
IF UPDATE(ActivationStatus)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tblCustomers
        SET tblCustomers.ActivationStatus = inserted.ActivationStatus
        FROM tblCustomers, inserted
        WHERE tblCustomers.ParentCustomerID = inserted.CustomerID               
    END

-- IF RateClass updated, need to update any child Customers too
IF UPDATE(RateClass)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tblCustomers
        SET tblCustomers.RateClass = inserted.RateClass
        FROM tblCustomers, inserted
        WHERE tblCustomers.ParentCustomerID = inserted.CustomerID               
    END
```

When I try an update I get error: 
*Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)*

Clearly a recursion problem is happening, and it kind of makes sense why it is happening, but it should be possible to do something like this right?  How can I achieve this?

Please note I would rather not do `SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF` because I'm unsure what effect that will have on the many other triggers we have throughout the database.

Thank you!

Comment: You need some sort of end condition that will terminate the recursive updates. what is happening is that the update the child customers records is triggering updates to it's child customer records.

Comment: @Shiva Thanks.  I was thinking that when it gets to the child records, the WHERE condition will prevent the update from running since the children themselves do not have any children.  I got the error when I updated a parent that had like two children (and those children had no children)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added

`AND ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) = 1)`

To the If conditions to stop it from recursing on the child updates.  Still testing but so far seems to be working

Comment: Seems like this would prevent grandchildren from getting the updates, but I think I'm ok with that

Comment: I ended up using  (SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(OBJECT_ID('dpmgr.tblCustomers_UTrig'), 'AFTER' , 'DML')) to check for that specific trigger    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182737.aspx

Comment: Better yet is    SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID, 'AFTER' , 'DML').  @@PROCID gets the object_id of the current trigger